# codeigniter uri/router checking

Tags: codeigniter, session, uri

I am using `codeigniter` and have a controller in which I assign some search criteria's to be stored in session like this:

```
$srchCriteria = array(
'stockCode'=>$this->input->post('srchScode'),
'qty'=>$this->input->post('srchQty'),                           
'class' => $this->router->fetch_class(),
'method' => $this->router->fetch_method(),
);
$this->session->set_userdata('srchCriteria',$srchCriteria);
```

And on basis of this criteria output is generated. Now I need to clear this criteria if the user navigates to another page other than this page. i.e every time the user visits the search page the search criteria should be cleared except for pagination. For this purpose I checked the class and method variables in core controller like this:

```
$srchCriteria  = $this->session->userdata('srchCriteria');      
$className = $this->router->fetch_class();
$methodName = $this->router->fetch_method(); 

if(!empty( $srchCriteria['class']  ) && !empty( $srchCriteria['method'] )){
    if( ($srchCriteria['method'] != $methodName){               
      $this->session->set_userdata('srchCriteria',array());
    }
}
```

But it is not working please guide me in right way. What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->session->unset_userdata('srchCriteria');` instead of `$this->session->set_userdata('srchCriteria',array());`

Comment: have tried it  but no result. my problem is on the checking if loop. it always clears. dont know the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in this `IF` ? Try `echo 'I am in IF block at line 1234';` `echo 'Method name in session is'.$srchCri['method'];` `echo 'Method name var is '.$methodName;` inside the IF;

Comment: yes i have echoed it. it works fine when there is exit keyword, when exit is commented and if we are  checking in-equality it always enters the loop  and in other case it doesnt enter the loop. is there any problem in comparing $this->router->fetch_class()?

Comment: **if( ($srchCriteria['method'] != $methodName){** ........ there isn't a closing parenthesis here?